# Node command no longer found after zsh window is closed

Tags: node.js, macos, zsh

When I open a new zsh window, `node`, `npm`, and `yarn` commands are not found, but `nvm` is.  After I run `nvm use 18`, then `node`, `npm`, and `yarn` are available.

Everything's working great until I open a new zsh tab (or window or VSCode with hosted zsh), then `node`, `npm`, and `yarn` are again not found for that window (but like before, `nvm` is).

NVM was installed using the command in the according to the [installation instructions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#install--update-script), which also updated my `.zshrc` file to load NVM.

How do I ensure that access to these commands is persisted across any zsh window?  Is there a reason these aren't getting saved in my `path`?

Comment: Is nvm installed properly?

Comment: You might have to add some lines in .zshrc: https://gist.github.com/mike-casas/6d489bebf48d89f5109cd1395aabe150

Comment: Insufficient information. How are you installing those commands? Does the installation instructions for those command tell you to modify your *~/.zshrc* to add the directory containing those commands to your `PATH` env var? Presumably `nvm use 18` is modifying the `PATH` env var of your current shell instance but not modifying the startup config file for your shell.

Comment: Is the repeated installation of `yarn` really necessary, or is it sufficient to do a `nvm use 18` in the new shell?

Comment: Updated post with more info in response to @DanielA.White, @Ricky Mo, and @Kurtis Rader.  @user1934428: seems not; `yarn` is available as soon as `node` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `nvm` didn't have a default version of Node.js set.  I expected this would have been automatic behavior, but perhaps something was funked up with my environment.

To resolve this, all I had to do was to run one of the commands from [Set default node version](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#set-default-node-version) in the docs:

```bash
nvm alias default node # this refers to the latest installed version of node
nvm alias default 18 # this refers to the latest installed v18.x version of node
nvm alias default 18.12  # this refers to the latest installed v18.12.x version of node
```